# Iptables Accept All From Specific Ip And Port

Tags: iptables, firewall, udp, netfilter, iptables-persistent

I want to accept all traffic that is coming from an IP address and its specific port to any of my ports.
Here is the configuration:
[image: configuration]

Details:
I am using Jitsi in a server, and I want to reach Jitsi from another server2 (client). Client has firewall on it, which blocks everything except https and ssh, by default.
Jitsi meet conference process (Without STUN, which allows peer to peer connection) goes like that:

- Client sends a connection request from any of its port to the 10000th port of Jitsi.
- Jitsi accepts the request to its 10000, and sends the answer to the port that the request comes from.
- Client can't see the answer, since firewall has blocked it, because the answer came to a random port.

So I need to accept all traffic that comes from the IP of Jitsi server and its specifically port 10000 to any of my ports.

I tried to add these to rules.chains:

```
-A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.1 --sport 10000 -j POLACCEPT
```

But it didn't work. It gave me error on systemctl restart netfilter-persistent.
By the way, I can see the incoming packets in tcpdump results, I guess this is because udp packets are coming and then iptables blocks them, but tcpdump may still be able to see them.

Is there a solution for this and what is it?

Comment: I edited @AdminBee But I solved at last, I will share in the answer

Comment: Thank you, and congratulations on finding the solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the protocol has the be specified.
`-A PREROUTING -p udp -s 10.0.0.1 --sport 10000 -j POLACCEPT`
line should work for this. The -p means protocol, it is now specified as udp.

According to the answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/415717/setting-iptables-rule-for-all-protocols-for-specific-source-and-destination-port
This is not permitted because, IP transport layer can have protocols that aren't tied to ports.